# Yield и потоки и все все все

Tags: c#, многопоточность, yield

Оператор yield

```
class UserCollection
{
    public static IEnumerable Power()
    {
        yield return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Оператор yield из .Net Reflector - перенесенный в рялии C# и Visual Studio

```
class UserCollection
{
    public static IEnumerable Power()
    {
        return new ClassPower(-2);
    }

    private sealed class ClassPower : IEnumerable<object>,  IEnumerator<object>, IEnumerator, IDisposable
    {
        // Поля.
        private int state;
        private object current;
        private int initialThreadId;

        // Конструктор.
        public ClassPower(int state)
        {
            this.state = state;
            this.initialThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        }

        //private bool IEnumerator.MoveNext() // Так в Рефлекторе
        bool IEnumerator.MoveNext()
        {
            switch (this.state)
            {
                case 0:
                    this.state = -1;
                    this.current = "Hello world!";
                    this.state = 1;
                    return true;

                case 1:
                    this.state = -1;
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

        IEnumerator<object> IEnumerable<object>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            if ((Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == this.initialThreadId) && (this.state == -2))
            {
               this.state = 0;
               return this;
            }
            return new UserCollection.ClassPower(0);
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            // Так в Рефлекторе 
            //return this.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Object>.GetEnumerator(); 

            return (this as IEnumerable<object>).GetEnumerator();
        }

        void IEnumerator.Reset()
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
        }

        // Свойства.
        object IEnumerator<object>.Current
        {
            get
            {
                return this.current;
            }
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                return this.current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Меня интересует строка и как ее комментирует автор

```
this.initialThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
```

данная строка свидетельствует о синхронизации и доступа к этой коллекции как к разделяемому ресурсу.
Почему именно при работе с yield коллекция воспринимается как разделяемый ресурс и нужна вообще в принципе работа с потоками?

См. рисунок как я понял работу оператора yield
и может т.к это в эту коробку все операторы yield помещают свое значение , то может поэтому нужна работа с потоками? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обратите внимание на функцию `IEnumerable<object>.GetEnumerator()`.

Данный объект реализует как `IEnumerable`, так и `IEnumerator`. Состояние `-2` означает, что объект «свежий», только что вернулся из вызова функции `Power`, и его энумерация ещё не начиналась. В этой ситуации, когда тут же вызывается `GetEnumerator` в том же потоке (а это происходит в подавляющем большинстве случаев: например, при вызове `foreach (var x in Power())`), то из соображений эффективности можно вернуть этот же объект (т. к. он служит и энумератором тоже).

Но если энумерация уже прошла, внутреннее состояние объекта может быть испорчено, для этого случая возвращают новый объект. Точно так же если энумерация производится в другом потоке, то чтобы избежать необходимости синхронизации, лучше создать новый объект.

Остановимся специально на последнем пункте. Если вдруг `IEnumerable` уйдёт в другой поток, и оттуда буден вызван метод `GetEnumerator()`, и одновременно в основном потоке будет тоже вызван этот же метод, то без проверки thread id может случиться так, что *оба* потока пройдут одновременно проверку `this.state == -2`, и получат *один и тот же* объект! В результате при энумерации они будут мешать друг другу. В этом случае мы даём «выиграть» тому же потоку, который создал объект.

Таким образом, это специальная оптимизация для обычного случая (выделение только одного объекта); «необычные» случаи использования проходят более сложным путём.

---

Подробнее по теме: Jon Skeet, [C# in Depth. Iterator block implementation details: auto-generated state machines](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx).